# libgdx ashley ecs framework - Small Object Components vs. Large Object Component

Tags: java, libgdx, entity-component-system

On libGDX ashley ecs framework, we are required to split large `object` into `Components`. I want to see what is the edge of `SpriteComponent` (`Sprite` is still a large `object`) to `TextureComponent`, `SizeComponent`, `PositionComponent`, `OriginComponent`, `RotationComponent`, `ScaleComponent` (or `TransformComponent` & `SizeComponent`).

```
TextureComponent - @field: TextureRegion region
SizeComponent - @field: float width, float height
TransformComponent - @field: Vector2 position, Vector2 origin, Vector2 scale, float rotation

entity.add(texture);
entity.add(size);
entity.add(transform);

V.S

SpriteComponent - @field: Sprite sprite

entity.add(sprite);

or the combination of both

entity.add(texture);
entity.add(size);
entity.add(transform);
entity.add(sprite);

SpriteSystem - overrides the size and transform components
RenderingSystem - uses the texture, size, transform components to draw object
```

**Question** do you required to use `SpriteComponent` if the `Texture` ,`Transform` & `Size` `Component` is already added as `Entity` `Components`?

I'm not sure on my `SpriteSystem` if that is the proper behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, the goal of an entity component system such as Ashley is to have systems handle all the components of the entities of your game. Suppose you split your `SpriteComponent` into `TextureComponent`, `SizeComponent` and `TransformComponent`, will you implement a `TextureSystem` or a `SizeSystem`? Those systems will iterate over all entities, and if they have the specific component, perform some logic, each frame. Maybe your specific game will change the size or the texture of most of the entities on a frame by frame basis, but to me, it is unlikely, and your performance will suffer from this design. The examples shown in Ashley and other ECS give pretty good examples of what a component is likely to be: inputs, position, velocity, rendering... and for the moment maybe the good thing to do is to stick to it.

Comment: So you were saying that using large object like Sprite is not a good idea to use in ECS?

Comment: It all comes down to tradeoffs. You need your systems to be activated for a good reason. You need to be able to adapt the logic of your game easily. Sometimes components are mere markers that trigger functionality, sometimes they are big fat chunks of code (especially for dealing with the player) in which case, you're perfectly entitled to break down not so much the components themselves, but the systems. You're not compelled to have your systems be implemented in a unique class.